# kibana watcher to send array of json objects

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create an alert in **TheHive4** with some observables using watcher. Using the postman tool I am able to send API requests, below is the postman request body. observables are under artifacts. An array of JSON Objects.

```
{
  "title": "Test Title",
  "description": "Testing alert creation through the API",
  "tags": ["testing" , "API"],
  "type": "external",
  "source": "postman",
  "sourceRef": "111111",
  "severity": 1,
  "tlp": 0,
  "artifacts": [
    { "dataType": "ip", "data": "127.0.0.1", "message": "localhost" },
    { "dataType": "hash", "data": "lasgjjaskrgjiwrj", "message": "localhost" }
  ]
}
```

In Kibana Devtools I replicated the same request as given below.

```
    PUT _watcher/watch/Watcher_to_Hive2
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "5m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "testindex-1*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "process": "YASHUKASH.EXE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "compare": {
      "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
        "gt": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "victorops": {
      "webhook": {
        "scheme": "http",
        "host": "15.00.00.130",
        "port": 9000,
        "method": "post",
        "path": "api/alert",
        "params": {
          "process": "{{ctx.watch_id}}",
          "description": "description",
          "source": "source",
          "type": "type",
          "sourceRef": "Watcher1",
          "title": "Watcher_test"
          
        },
        "data-raw":{
          "title": "Test Ale",
  "description": "Testing alert creation through the API",
  "tags": ["testing" , "API"],
  "type": "external",
  "source": "postman",
  "sourceRef": "10299",
  "severity": 1,
  "tlp": 0,
  "organization":"test",
  "artifacts": {
    [
    { "dataType": "ip", "data": "127.0.0.1", "message": "localhost" },
    { "dataType": "hash", "data": "lasgjjaskrgjiwrj", "message": "localhost" }
  ]},
        "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Bearer Token******Token",
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        "body": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Kibana watcher also I can create an alert to TheHive4 but cannot use artifacts (Array of JSON objects). If I use artifacts it is giving me 400 errors. Error is as follows

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[50:7] [script] unknown field [dataType]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "[50:7] [script] unknown field [dataType]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

How do I define an array of JSON objects in watcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that but you need to do 2 changes.

1. By sending the parameters in the body in text format.
2. Change the HTTP method type to POST from PUT.
   The sample code you need to enter is given below.

   **POST** /_Watcher/watch/{watch id}/_execute

   ```
    {
      "trigger": {
        "schedule": {
          "interval": "5m"
        }
      },
      "input": {
        "search": {
          "request": {
            "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
            "indices": [
              "Test_indices*"
            ],
            "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
            "body": {
              "size": 0,
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "process": "ABC.EXE"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "condition": {
        "compare": {
          "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
            "gt": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "actions": {
        "victorops": {
          "webhook": {
            "scheme": "http",
            "host": "15.00.00.130",
            "port": 9000,
            "method": "post",
            "path": "api/alert",
            "params": {},
            "headers": {
              "Authorization": "Bearer your_token",
              "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            "body": """
                {
                 "title": "Test",
                 "description": "Testing alert",
                 "tags": ["testing","API"],
                 "type": "Test",
                 "source": "Test_Source",
                 "sourceRef": "Test_ref",
                 "severity": 1,
                 "tlp": 0,
                 "artifacts": [{
                     "dataType": "ip",
                     "data": "127.0.0.1",
                     "message": "localhost"
                    },
                    {
                      "dataType": "hash",
                      "data": "lasgjjaskrgjiwrj",
                      "message": "localhost"
                    },
                     {
                      "dataType": "hash",
                      "data": "processname",
                      "message": "myprocess"
                    }]
                }
            """
          }
        }
      }
    }
   ```

`

I hope by this you can create an alert by Kibana Devtools with observables in TheHive4.